# Распределенные вычисления на Android

Tags: сеть, клиент-сервер, android, java

Здравствуйте!

Возник такой вопрос. Есть два мобильных телефона на базе Android, есть некий сервер.
На сервере ставится задача: "Сервер, ищи простые числа". Сервер должен сформировать задачу для каждого мобильного устройства и диапазон значений, в котором нужно производить поиск простых чисел и дать каждому устройству задание. Затем устройства ищут эти числа и отсылают результат на сервер.

Сервер формирует результат. Вопрос в том, как происходит формирование задания?
В одном случае нужно найти простые числа в диапазоне,  в другом случае необходимо что-то смоделировать. Написать уникальную программу для каждого отдельного случая возможно, как написать универсальную программу, способную решать все новые и новые задачи? Может, решение уже есть?

Заранее благодарен)

Comment: извиняюсь за коментарий не по теме, но я очень давно не видел здесь адекватных вопросов.
самому стало интересно посмотреть ответы

Comment: Спасибо) Боюсь, я сформировал вопрос кривовато, но если вы поняли, то значит всё норм)

Comment: Присоединюсь к коментариям не по теме, вопрос и вправду интересный ..... но зачем ? в большинстве случаев общение между клиентами и сервером превысит по времени вычисления самого сервера.  Действительно интересный вопрос,  но не могу представить практическое применение.
Чтоб совсем не отходить от темы ─ почитайте про распределенные вычисления, без привязки к android и конкретному яп.

Comment: @gadfil самый насущьный пример как по мне - создание аналога ГПУ, ГПГПУ, ГПЦПУ, и тп. вычислений для ПК (Биткоины, майнинг...).    
то есть это огромнейшая "возможность" для хакеров встроить в свою программу такой код, и использовать вычислительные мощьности своих юзеров в своих целях...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Android есть возможностбь динамической загрузки исполняемого кода. Инструмент, при помощи которого это производится называется [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) 
Я сейчас занимаюсь задачей несколько подобной вашей.  
То есть вам нужно скомпилировать где-то код, который нужно выполнить, распределить его каким-то образом, и отослать Push Notification на все целевые устройства, который оповестит их о том, что для них есть новая задача, они скачают скомпилированный вами код, и запустят его выполнение...

Comment: Дааа, именно то что нужно!) Можете посоветовать какую-то статью с примерами исходников?)

Comment: сейчас не смог найти пример, по которому я делал свою задачу, но что-то подобное вот тут
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Answer (score 0):

Вообще у самого недавно появился проект, где должны происходить *непредвиденные вычисления*, пока что до этой стадии не дошли, и никакие материалы я не копал, но пока что предполагается оформить это в виде *сценариев*, алгоритмы которых известны, и которые могут биндить свои результаты друг другу. Если совсем грубо, то там произвольные выборки данных, которые могут зависеть друг от друга, соответственно есть несколько сценариев поиска, которые известно как реализовать, а само описание сценария говорит, какие данные предоставлены для поиска и какие брать из соседнего сценария.